# Can the Loch Ness monster question be reopened?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, reopen

Have I done enough to improve [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/90372/is-optical-illusion-responsible-for-loch-ness-monster) to get it reopened?

**Coda:**  If the first comment by `WetSavannaAnimal aka Rod Vance` had been posted as an answer, I would have accepted it and we wouldn't be having this discussion.

Comment: But what is your question? If rouge waves are possible or if rouge waves could be identified as a Lonch Ness monster?

Comment: @jinawee, I am suggesting that rogue waves occur sporatically and create the illusions of monsters. We know the waves occur and the suspicion is that when a rogue wave encounters a steep side somewhere away from shore it will disappear without reaching shore (like the normal more shallow waves we are used to seeing).

Comment: But what is the precise physics question? If it's just _Could this shadow-like area explain the sightings?_ It's not about physics, it's about physchology.

Comment: I like the idea of rouge waves - sounds pretty

Comment: @FredKline: Your comment here is exactly the reason why your question should be posted on skeptics.SE.

Comment: @KyleKanos, If we rephrase the scenario I edited into the OP to read: _A physicist is ... and sees the posted image ..., she would say, "Wow, a rogue wave. You don't see that very often."_ It would be up to the psychologists to explain how people would see it as a monster. Anyway, I've passed this idea along to **Myth Busters.** Maybe, they will see some merit in it.

Comment: @FredKline: The whole [point of this site](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is to answer questions about **physics** and your edited question still shows no **physics** question.

Comment: I don't see how this is a physics question (which is the sole purpose of this site)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you had a question about fluid dynamics and wave formation then that's physics. Why waves might look like mythical creatures is not.